# An ideal Visual Studio template that could be used for Entity Framework as a separate layer

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm new to entity framework.  I would like to know if I want to deploy my EF inside a separate layer/project, which visual studio template would best accommodate this layer.  Should I use a "Class Library" or a simple "Console Application".  Besides some of the known templates, is there any rule or guideline for picking the right template for what we intend to define as a separate layer/project?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your EF stuff should go in an Class Library project, so that will output a DLL that can be consumed either by a Web Application or a Console/Windows Form Application without changes.

Usually you have a single "Runnable" project, which tends to be the default project. This can be an ASP.Net applcation, Console, Windows Forms, Windows Service, etc.

This project acts as the entry point to your application logic, since the rest of the projects are DLL they're far more reusable than exeutable ones.

Answer (score 1):

What you describer there is not a class template.

Windows Application / Console Application / Class Library refer to the output type. A console app must have a "Main" method and based on that VS knows to compile the code into an executable. When you start the executable the Main is called.

In general, consider having a single project of type console app or windows app, and set it to be the start-up project (right click on it > set as startup project). Put the bulk of your code in a library and call it from the console project.

In particular for EF, you definitely a library to hold all database related code - i.e. separate from the rest of the code.